# <template> clone but with texts from user input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a comment section for my page, I used the template element to create the box and format for my user's pic and name but i'm having difficulties adding the text received from the user to get into the box. right now it creates the box and just puts the text outside/under it. How can I create a element to store inside the template?

```js
function postComment() {
  //Clone new box for comment
  var temp = document.getElementsByTagName("template")[0];
  var clone = temp.content.cloneNode(true);
  var newComment = document.getElementById("new-comment");
  newComment.appendChild(clone)

  //Get comment
  var userComment = document.getElementById("comment-box").value;
  var text = document.createElement('p');
  text.innerHTML = userComment;
  newComment.appendChild(text)

  //reset the comment box
  document.getElementById("comment-box").value = "";
}

var post = document.getElementById("post");
post.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  postComment()

})
```

```css
.comment-box,
.post-comment .list {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px black;
}

.comment-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.post-comment .list {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.post-comment .list .user {
  display: flex;
  padding: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.post-comment .list .user img {
  height: 38px;
  width: 38px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.comment-section .name {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.post-comment .list .day {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.post-comment {
  padding: 0 0 15px 58px
}

#comment-box {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.comment-box .user {
  display: flex;
  width: min-content;
}

.comment-box .image img {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="comment-section">
    <div class="post-comment">
      <div class="list">
        <div class="user">
          <div class="user-image"><img src="./images/ok.webp"></div>
          <div class="user-name">
            <div class="name">TOM</div>
            <div class="day">100 days ago</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="comment">LOREM IPSUN DABUN VUB</div>
      </div>

      <template>
            <div class="list">
              <div class="user">
                <div class="user-image"><img src="./images/Animal-Crossing-Tom-Nook-with-Money.jpg"></div>
                <div class="user-name">
                  <div class="name">Tom Nook</div>
                  <div class="day">1 second ago</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </template>

      <div id="new-comment"></div>

      <div class="comment-box">
        <div class="user">
          <div class="user-image"><img src="./images/OK.webp"></div>
          <form>
            <textarea name="comment" placeholder="YOUR MESSAGE" id="comment-box"></textarea>
            <button id="post">Comment</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and see if this suits your requirements:

```js
function postComment() {
  //Get comment
  var userComment = document.getElementById("comment-box").value;

  var html = '<div class="list">' +
    '<div class="user">' +
    '<div class="user-image"><img src="./images/Animal-Crossing-Tom-Nook-with-Money.jpg"></div>' +
    '<div class="user-name">' +
    '<div class="name">Tom Nook</div>' +
    '<div class="day">1 second ago</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div id="new-comment">' + userComment + '</div>' +
    '</div>';


  var template = document.getElementsByTagName("template")[0];
  template.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", html);

  //reset the comment box
  document.getElementById("comment-box").value = "";
}

var post = document.getElementById("post");
post.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  postComment()

})
```

```css
.comment-box,
.post-comment .list {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px black;
}

.comment-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.post-comment .list {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.post-comment .list .user {
  display: flex;
  padding: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.post-comment .list .user img {
  height: 38px;
  width: 38px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.comment-section .name {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="comment-section">
    <div class="post-comment">
      <div class="list">
        <div class="user">
          <div class="user-image"><img src="./images/ok.webp"></div>
          <div class="user-name">
            <div class="name">TOM</div>
            <div class="day">100 days ago</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="comment">LOREM IPSUN DABUN VUB</div>
      </div>

      <template></template>

      <div class="comment-box">
        <div class="user">
          <div class="user-image"><img src="./images/OK.webp"></div>
          <form>
            <textarea name="comment" placeholder="YOUR MESSAGE" id="comment-box"></textarea>
            <button id="post">Comment</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh yeah it helped in this case, I didn't realize u could just hard code the template into the function and add on the html so I tried cloning which i'm not too familar with, but thank you for the help!